# magento 2: Module upgrade error

Tags: php, magento, magento2

There is a known issue in magento 2:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29015069/Magento-2-URL-key-for-specified-store-already-exists.html

i have created a module to solve the above issue. when i run the command for upgrade. I get this error.

```
1 exception(s): 
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Jjcommerce_CatalogUrlRewrite data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
```

And now here is my registration.php file code

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jjcommerce_CatalogUrlRewrite',
    __DIR__
);
```

Here is module.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jjcommerce_CatalogUrlRewrite" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

and this is di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\AnchorUrlRewriteGenerator" type="Jjcommerce\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\AnchorUrlRewriteGenerator" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator" type="Jjcommerce\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator" />
</config>
```

After upgrade i get this error in console.
[image: This is error when i run upgrade command.]

Please help what should do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just update your setup_version to current required version. Below file update for your solution module.xml file